# ScrollView не прокручивает до конца

Tags: java, android, android-scrollview

Пролистываю до конца, но кнопка все равно остается под BottomAppBar.
Мне нужно, чтобы ScrollView прокручивался от верхнего ToolBar до BottomAppBar.
Скриншот, где кнопка после пролистывания находится под BottomAppBar: https://i.stack.imgur.com/x9Vzy.png

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/dark_gray"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/light_gray">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolBar1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="Профиль"
                android:textStyle="bold"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAlignment="textEnd"
                android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
                android:text="Баланс"/>

        </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <include layout="@layout/activity_main_partial"/>
    </ScrollView>

    <com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar
        android:id="@+id/bottomAppBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/light_gray"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom">

    </com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

main_activity_partial:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/mainPartialLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="30dp"/>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_end="30dp"/>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/profileView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
        android:background="@color/light_gray"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="4:1.4"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/guideline2"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/guideline1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="Ваша статистика"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/guideline2"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/guideline1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/profileView"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/statsView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:background="@color/light_gray"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="4:1.4"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/guideline2"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/guideline1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/textView"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="Ежедневный бонус"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/guideline2"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/guideline1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/statsView"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/bonusView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:background="@color/light_gray"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="4:2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/guideline2"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/guideline1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/textView2"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/exitButton"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/red"
        android:text="Выйти"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="4:0.75"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/guideline2"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/guideline1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/bonusView"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: он под меню находится, приподнимите нижний край на 56dp типа такого marginBottom="56dp" тогда он будет до конца скроллиться

Comment: Я не знаю как сделать, чтобы layout ScrollView'a располагался четко всегда между верхним и нижним барами, чтобы при разных экранах все работало нормально. Можешь подсказать, как реализовать?

Comment: приложите пож всю разметку данного файла

Comment: Отредактировал пост

Comment: интересовал макет где находится этот скрол, или вас там три виджета без общего контейнера?

Comment: А, извини, отредактировал.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот например можно переместить это все в androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/dark_gray"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/light_gray"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolBar1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="Профиль"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
                android:text="Баланс"
                android:textAlignment="textEnd" />

        </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/bottomAppBar"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginVertical="56dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/appBarLayout">

        <include layout="@layout/activity_main_partial" />
    </ScrollView>

    <com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar
        android:id="@+id/bottomAppBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/light_gray"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

выглядит так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

либо добавить просто одну строку к ScrollView:

```
android:layout_marginVertical="56dp"
```

в итоге будет так:

```
<ScrollView
android:layout_marginVertical="56dp"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <include layout="@layout/activity_main_partial"/>
</ScrollView>
```

и будет выглядеть так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Огромное спасибо, помогло.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый нажав на галочку слева от него.